# Python PIL int object not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I have an image treatment program that is similar to photoshop but very simple (buttons and image display). In my program you can choose the image you want to use and modify. I'm currently working on a popart part of the program, but when I use an image of CheGevara (called "chev.png"), it gives the  following error (the function is "def PopArt()"):

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\EduPython\App\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1538, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\omar\Desktop\azer\Test 1.py", line 52, in PopArt
    o=int((p[0]+p[1]+p[2])/3)
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

When I use other images like "fleur1.png" or "face.png", it works fine and displays the modification just fine. Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import*
import tkinter as Tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog, DISABLED
import os
import ntpath
from PIL import Image

def EchelleDeGris():
    Ima2=Image.new("RGB",(z[0],z[1]))
    px=Ima1.load()
    px1=Ima2.load()
    for x in range(z[0]):
        for y in range(z[1]):
            p=px[x,y]
            o=int((p[0]+p[1]+p[2])/3)
            px1[x,y]=(o,o,o)
    Ima2.save("ImageMod.png")
    im2 = PhotoImage(file="ImageMod.png")
    main.image = im2
    I2 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im2)
    I2.grid(row=0, column=3, rowspan =6)

def SupprimerImage():
    I2 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=imt)
    I2.grid(row=0, column=3, rowspan =6)

def Luminosite():
    Ima2=Image.new("RGB",(z[0],z[1]))
    px=Ima1.load()
    px1=Ima2.load()
    for x in range(z[0]):
        for y in range(z[1]):
            p=px[x,y]
            px1[x,y]=(p[0]+S1.get(),p[1]+S1.get(),p[2]+S1.get())
    Ima2.save("ImageMod.png")
    im2 = PhotoImage(file="ImageMod.png")
    main.image = im2
    I2 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im2)
    I2.grid(row=0, column=3, rowspan =6)

def AnnulerModifications():
    I2 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im1)
    I2.grid(row=0, column=3, rowspan =6)

def PopArt():
    Ima2=Image.new("RGB",(z[0],z[1]))
    px=Ima1.load()
    px1=Ima2.load()
    for x in range(z[0]):
        for y in range(z[1]):
            p=px[x,y]
            o=int((p[0]+p[1]+p[2])/3)
            if o<85:
                px1[x,y]=(0,0,255)
            elif 85<o<170:
                px1[x,y]=(0,255,0)
            elif o>170:
                px1[x,y]=(255,0,0)
    Ima2.save("ImageMod.png")
    im2 = PhotoImage(file="ImageMod.png")
    main.image = im2
    I2 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im2)
    I2.grid(row=0, column=3, rowspan =6)






main=Tk()

main.withdraw()
currdir = os.getcwd()
a = filedialog.askopenfilename()
main.deiconify()

main.configure(background="#a1dbcd")
main.title("Photoshop Version.Megzari")

Ima1=Image.open(a)
z=Ima1.size
nux=Image.new("RGB",(z[0],z[1]))
nuxy=nux.load()
for x in range(z[0]):
    for y in range(z[1]):
        nuxy[x,y]=(255,255,255)
nux.save("Blank.png")








if z>(400,400):
    im2 = Tkinter.PhotoImage(file="ImageBlank.png")
    main.image = im2
    I2 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im2)
    I2.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=0, column=1, rowspan =6)
    T1 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im2)
    T1.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=0, column=3, rowspan =6)
    B1 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Echelle de gris", command = EchelleDeGris, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39", state=DISABLED)
    B1.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=0, column=2)
    B3 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Appliquer Luminosité", command = Luminosite, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39", state=DISABLED)
    B3.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=2, column=2)
    S1 = Scale(main, from_=0, to=254, orient=HORIZONTAL, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39", state=DISABLED, length = 200)
    S1.grid(row=1, column=2)
    B2 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Supprimer Image", command = SupprimerImage, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39", state=DISABLED)
    B2.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=4, column=2)
    B3 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Annuler Modifications", command = AnnulerModifications, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39", state=DISABLED)
    B3.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=3, column=2)
    B4 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Pop Art", command = PopArt, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39", state=DISABLED)
    B4.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=5, column=2)
elif z<(400,400):
    im1 = Tkinter.PhotoImage(file=a)
    I1 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im1)
    I1.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=0, column=1, rowspan =6)
    imt = Tkinter.PhotoImage(file="Blank.png")
    T1 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=imt)
    T1.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=0, column=3, rowspan =6)
    B1 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Echelle de gris", command = EchelleDeGris, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39", state=NORMAL)
    B1.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=0, column=2)
    B3 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Appliquer Luminosité", command = Luminosite, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39")
    B3.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=2, column=2)
    S1 = Scale(main, from_=0, to=254, orient=HORIZONTAL, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39", length = 200)
    S1.grid(row=1, column=2)
    B2 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Supprimer Image", command = SupprimerImage, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39")
    B2.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=4, column=2)
    B3 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Annuler Modifications", command = AnnulerModifications, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39")
    B3.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=3, column=2)
    B4 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Pop Art", command = PopArt, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39")
    B4.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=5, column=2)

s=S1.get()




main.mainloop()
```

Here are the images I used (all of them are png, but chev.png and fleur.png were converted from jpg, and fleur1.png was resized from fleur.png):

[chev.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNYfU.png)

EDIT: the other images are in the comments because i can't put more than 1 link in my post

Comment: I can't post more than 1 link (less than 10 reputation) so I'm putting them in the comments: [face.png][2] ; [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bz9Gd.png

Comment: [fleur1.png][3] ; [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtgH4.png

Comment: [fleur.png][4] ; [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqPYr.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact i found the solution. My chev.png was a level of grey image, so his pixels value was a single integer, where as the other ones were tuples (R,G,B). So all i had to do was check the type of the pixel:

```
if type(p)==int:
```

then if it is an integer, he converts it into a tuple:

```
p=(p,p,p)
```

and you're all set ;)

Comment: It would be better to convert the image to RGB. If the image is indexed then `p` will be a color index, and the tuple `(p, p, p)` will not be representative of the pixel's actual color at all. Just do `px=Ima1.load().convert('RGB')`.